# Initialising MdDialog in angular material , instead of initialising MdDialog from constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I  am  trying out md-dialog as mentioned in angular material

`https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples`

```
constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

openDialog(): void {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  this.animal = result;
});
}
```

It's working fine, my problem is i can't use constructor to initialize `MdDialog`

Is there some way where i can initialise `MdDialog` and use it something like this

```
let dialogRef = new MdDialog()
```

Comment: There's not, `MdDialog` is a service, meaning it has only one instance. Why would you do that ?

Comment: You have to pass the following parameters in such case `constructor(
      private _overlay: Overlay,
      private _injector: Injector,
      @Inject(MD_DIALOG_SCROLL_STRATEGY) private _scrollStrategy,
      @Optional() private _location: Location,
      @Optional() @SkipSelf() private _parentDialog: MdDialog) {`

Comment: If you want a second dialog just make another **DialogOverviewExampleDialogV2** and open that one.

Comment: The class which i am using to open dialog is being initialised by some other class and hence i cannot pass it in constructor

Comment: why cant you use a constructor?

Comment: @Faisal
I can't use the constructor because, the initilization of classes hapeens something like this.
Class A ----> Class B ---> Class C -> My_final_class_wer_dialog is used.

If i used constructor then i have pass the refrence form Class A ---> Class B --> C --> final class, whcih dosent makes any sense

Comment: @AjinkyaDhote are these classes provided services or just regular classes?

Comment: @WillHowell they are just regular classes

Comment: @AjinkyaDhote I don't know if it's recommended, but you should be able to use `const dialog = injector.get(MdDialog)` to get an instance of the service. You may need to provide (and even inject) MdDialog in you NgModule, but I'm not sure.